Problem with calculating the limits of a SDE
If I have a function $P(t,T)$ such that it follows a SDE:
$$
dP(t,T) = P(t,T) (\mu(t)dt + \sigma(t) dW(t)) \tag{1}
$$
where $W(t)$ is a brownian motion,
how can I prove that $P(T,T)=1$?
Will I have to impose some bounds on my $\mu(t)$? The drift term $\mu(t)$ is pretty complicated, and has some unknown functions of $t$ in it. A minimum working example of $\mu(t)$ can be
$$
\mu(t)=x(t)+y(t)
$$
where both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are unknowns to me. Is there a way to go about this problem? Any help is highly appreciated. If you notice, the $P(t,T)$ is supposed to represent the bond price, hence I need it to be 1 at the final maturity time.

iirc in the HJM framework (i.e. we are directly given bond dynamics like in (1)) the conditions $P(T,T)=1$ (and $\sigma(T)=0$) are imposed, not derived. If instead you work starting from a interest-rate process then the condition $P(T,T)=1$ comes with the definition of the risk-neutral price of the bond.

I think that $P(T,T) = 1$ is from the definition of the process $t\mapsto P(t,T)$, which represents the bond price. Therefore, we cannot prove the definition.

With $\sigma(t)$ not depending on $T$ you cannot prove $P(T,T)=1,.$ Every textbook teaching the HJM model has special cases where you see some $\sigma(t,T)$ explicitly. In fact: I answered a post of yours nearly two years ago where you see the SDE for $P(t,T)$ and the volatility function $\sigma(t,T)$ for the Ho-Lee model. $P(T,T)=1$ holds by definition of the zero bond price.
